# Is integration against an indicator Wasserstein-Continuous

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, probability-distributions, integration, optimal-transportation

Let $\mathcal{P}_p(X)$ denote the Wasserstein space over a compact metric space $X$, and $1\leq p<\infty$.  Fix a non-empty closed subset $C\subseteq X$.  Then is the map:
$$
\mathbb{P} \mapsto \int_{x \in X} I_C(x) d\mathbb{P}(x),
$$
continuous on $P_p(X)$ with respect to the Wasserstein distance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $C$ isn't also open, find a sequence $(x_n)$ in $X\setminus C$ which converges to a point $x$ in $C$. Then the point measures $\delta_{x_n}$ converge to $\delta_x$ but their integrals against $1_C$ do not.